# Read File on HDFS Using Kerberos Authentication Using PySpark

Tags: pyspark, hdfs, kerberos, webhdfs

I have a HDFS Cluster with Kerberos Authentication. How can i read a file on HDFS using PySpark.

Comment: You need to create a keytab in the client, and ask HDFS admin to add your keytab to the conf.Let me know if this helps https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/cdh_sg_kadmin_kerberos_keytab.html

Comment: @Preetham I already have keytab created using kinit command. I am able read a csv file on HDFS using KerberosClient (hdfs python library). Just dont know how to do it using PySpark

Comment: Okay now you can initiate the pyspark with passing two more config --keytab <path_to_key_tab> --principal <principal_name>.

Comment: @Preetham I have doubt in this point only. I have no idea how to pass these two configs while creating SparkSession. Can you please help

Comment: This will help  spark-submit --master -–conf spark.yarn.keytab=path_to_keytab -–conf spark.yarn.principal=principal@REALM.COM 
, You have 2 options to have this while calling the spark submit or internally in your code you can set the same using SC config, remember if you do it inside the code make sure to sc.stop and restart

Comment: @Preetham i have used it inside code as below

SparkSession.appName("TEST").config('spark.yarn.keytab', 'path').config('spark.yarn.principal', 'u@CLOUDERA').master(master_ip).getOrCreate()
                
But it doesnot work. Is this correct Systax and config ?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to avoid too many comments , this is what you can do :

```
custom_conf={
                 "master":"local[*]",
                 "spark.executor.memory" : "44g",
                 "spark.executor.cores" : "60",
                 "spark.executor.instances":"60",
                 "spark.yarn.keytab" : <path to keytab>,
                 "spark.yarn.principal" : <principal name@domain>,
                 "appName" : <specify app name>
                    }

sc_conf = SparkConf()
sc = sc = SparkContext()

sc_conf.setAppName(custom_conf["appName"])
sc_conf.setMaster(custom_conf["master"])
sc_conf.set('spark.executor.memory', custom_conf["spark.executor.memory"])
sc_conf.set('spark.executor.cores', custom_conf["spark.executor.cores"])
sc_conf.set('spark.yarn.keytab', custom_conf["spark.yarn.keytab"])
sc_conf.set('spark.yarn.principal', custom_conf["spark.yarn.principal"])
sc_conf.set('spark.executor.instances', custom_conf["spark.executor.instances"])



try:
    sc.stop()
    sc = SparkContext(conf=sc_conf)
except:
    sc = SparkContext(conf=sc_conf)
```

then you can use the new sc for your processing.